# Issue with 'if statement' in a php form with multiple recipients

Tags: html, php

My php form has a `<select>` option for multiple recipients with an email address associated to each of them:

```
<select name="sendto">
  <option value="select">-- Select --</option>
  <option value="general">General</option>
  <option value="support">Support</option>
  <option value="sales">Sales</option>
</select>
```

I'm able to send and receive successfully only the '**General**' option, the rest fails. It's obvious the issue is with the '***if statement***' but I can't figure out what the problem is exactly. Any help? Thanks.

This is the php code:

```
<?php 
 $to = $_REQUEST['sendto'] ; 
 $from = $_REQUEST['Email'] ; 
 $name = $_REQUEST['Name'] ; 
 $headers = "From: $from"; 
 $subject = "Web Contact Data"; 

 $fields = array(); 
 $fields{"Name"} = "Name"; 
 $fields{"Company"} = "Company"; 
 $fields{"Email"} = "Email"; 
 $fields{"Phone"} = "Phone"; 
 $fields{"list"} = "Mailing List"; 
 $fields{"Message"} = "Message"; 

 $body = "We have received the following information:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){ $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); } 

 $headers2 = "From: noreply@my-site.com"; 
 $subject2 = "Thank you for contacting us"; 
 $autoreply = "Thank you for contacting us. Somebody will get back to you as soon as possible, usualy within 48 hours. If you have any more questions, please consult our website at www.my-site.com";


if ($sendto == 'general') { 
    $to = 'alex@my-site.com';
}
else if ($sendto == 'support') { 
    $to = 'alabanino@my-site.com'; 
}
else if ($sendto == 'sales') { 
    $to = 'alabanino@my-site.com'; 
}
else { //other options
    $to = 'alex@my-site.com'; 
}

 if($from == '') { print "You have not entered an email, please go back and try again"; } 
    else { 
 if($name == '') { print "You have not entered a name, please go back and try again"; } 
     else { 
 $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, '-fnoreply@yourmailer.com'); 
 $send2 = mail($from, $subject2, $autoreply, $headers2); 
 if($send){
     header( "Location: http://www.my-site.com/thankyou.html" );} 
 else {
     print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please notify webmaster@my-site.com"; 
   } 
 }
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Where is $sento defined? This will be 'working' cos it will be defaulting to your final else condition as all others fail.

You need to add this and it should work

```
$sendto = $_REQUEST['sendto']
```

Or else use `$to` insetad